# How do I use 'security set-keychain-settings' to prevent locking?

Tags: security, keychain

The command line tool [`security set-keychain-settings`](https://ss64.com/osx/security-keychain-settings.html) provides options for

- locking when the system sleeps (`-l`) and
- locking after a timeout (`-u`)

but does not seem to provide any options for reversing these settings?

How to I use  `security set-keychain-settings` to disable these options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run `security set-keychain-settings` without anything else it will turn off both "Lock when sleeping" and "Lock after  minutes of inactivity" for the 'login' Keychain. It will also set the default number of minutes back to 5.

From there you can turn on whatever settings you want.

Comment: That seems to work as far a settings go (the show as changed), but even if I `security set-keychain-settings` (no args) to keep my "Local Items" from locking, it insists on locking away, and [the only way](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/325724/4395) I can unlock it is with `security unlock-keychain` (no args).

Comment: That might be another problem entirely. Let me think on it.

Comment: Thanks. Any help will be much appreciated. Happy to formulate a new question, but I'm not even sure what to ask. E.g I can get into states where `unlock-keychain` refuses correct passwords (often an "Allow" dialog is active) and I need to kill `security_service` (or reboot!) after which which `unlock-keychain` accepts passwords again.

Comment: I'm still stuck where I was on this. Any thoughts on how to proceed. (More details [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/325724/4395).)

Comment: According to this doc: https://ss64.com/osx/security-keychain-settings.html omitting everything should disable the timeout as well:

`-t timeout      Specify timeout interval in seconds (omitting this option specifies "no timeout")`